distinguishing homogeneous and heterogeneous tuples in python function overloads
Suppose I have an interface Base with a lot of implementations
from abc import ABC

class Base(ABC): ...

class A(Base): ...
class B(Base): ...
class C(Base): ...
# ...
class Z(Base): ...

Now I want to define a composite class that holds a frozenset of such objects. There is a common interface Product and two implementations which take either a heterogeneous frozenset (MixedProduct) or a homogeneous frozenset of Zs (ZProduct)
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from dataclasses import dataclass


class Product(ABC):
    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def items(self) -> frozenset[Base]: ...


@dataclass(frozen=True)
class MixedProduct(Product):
    items: frozenset[Base]


@dataclass(frozen=True)
class ZProduct(Product):
    items: frozenset[Z]

there is a factory function that takes an arbitrary number of Base objects and returns the correct Product object
from collections.abc import Iterable
from typing_extensions import TypeGuard


def check_all_z(items: tuple[Base, ...]) -> TypeGuard[tuple[Z, ...]]:
    return all([isinstance(item, Z) for item in items])

def make_product(*items: Base) -> MixedProduct | ZProduct:
    # `items` is a tuple[Base, ...]
    if check_all_z(items):  # the TypeGuard tells MyPy that items: tuple[Z, ...] in this clause
        return ZProduct(frozenset(items))
    return MixedProduct(frozenset(items))

so this function returns a ZProduct only if all input items are Z and MixedProduct otherwise. Now I would like to narrow the return type of make_product as a Union doesn't capture the feasible input - return type relations. What I want would be sth like this
reveal_type(make_product(Z()))  # note: Revealed type is "ZProduct"
reveal_type(make_product(A()))  # note: Revealed type is "MixedProduct"
reveal_type(make_product(Z(), Z()))  # note: Revealed type is "ZProduct"
reveal_type(make_product(B(), A()))  # note: Revealed type is "MixedProduct"
reveal_type(make_product(B(), Z()))  # note: Revealed type is "MixedProduct" # also contains one Z!!

I go ahead and define two overloads
from typing import overload

@overload
def make_product(*items: Base) -> MixedProduct: ...


@overload
def make_product(*items: Z) -> ZProduct: ...


def make_product(*items):
    if check_all_z(
        items
    ):  # the TypeGuard tells MyPy that items: tuple[Z, ...] in this clause
        return ZProduct(frozenset(items))
    return MixedProduct(frozenset(items))

so the first overload is the "catch all" while the second one is the specialization for the only case where you would get a ZProduct. But now MyPy complains with
error: Overloaded function signature 2 will never be matched: signature 1's parameter type(s) are the same or broader  [misc]

So my question is, is there a way to just specialize the annotations for make_product for this one particular case that would return ZProduct in any other way? With overload it seems to only be possible if all the involved types have no overlaps whatsoever. That would mean I would have to define a Union of all other implementations of Base except Z and use that as input for the MixedProduct variant. But that also doesn't work, because you can have Z in the input items for the MixedProduct variant, just not all of them (see last reveal_type example above). FWIW using a Union of all implementations of Base (including Z) for the MixedProduct variant throws the same MyPy error.
How else would I be able to differentiate between homogeneous and heterogeneous tuples with type annotations to capture the correct input - return type relations in my case?
To be clear: the actual runtime code does what I intend, I just can't get the type annotations right.

Switch the @overloads around. If you get any further mypy errors to do with overload-overlaps, # type: ignore them - there's a fundamental type unsafety with what you're trying to do here, but it is unlikely to affect your code significantly unless you have lots of situations which look like a: Base = Z() (up-casting instances of Z into Base).

ah right, thanks for the quick response! Indeed I had it that way around before and got the other error. How would I go about removing that fundamental type unsafety? Btw if you write a response I can accept it :-)

Statically getting ZProduct to be inferred from make_product can be achieved by switching the @overloads around, like so:
@overload
def make_product(item: Z, /, *items: Z) -> ZProduct: ...  # type: ignore[overload-overlap]
@overload
def make_product(item: Base, /, *items: Base) -> MixedProduct: ...
def make_product(*items: Base) -> MixedProduct | ZProduct:
    if check_all_z(items):
        return ZProduct(frozenset(items))
    return MixedProduct(frozenset(items))

The # type: ignore[overload-overlap] is suppressing a mypy error which is warning you of a type unsafety:
>>> z1: Base = Z()
>>> z2: Base = Z()
>>> reveal_type(make_product(z1, z2))  # revealed type is "MixedProduct"

This unsafety is pretty bad, because MixedProduct is not a superclass of ZProduct, so static errors can easily propagate throughout the code if you're not careful.

There are a few ways to reduce this unsafety, such as:

Avoid type-annotating things as Base (use concrete types A, B, ... wherever possible), and avoid unions of A, B, ... with Z. This way, when items get passed to make_product, type-checkers will statically know when you have passed purely Z objects and correctly tell you that the resultant type is ZProduct.
Make MixedProduct a parent class of ZProduct. This way, even if ZProduct is not picked up due to Z instances being masked as Base instances, inferring MixedProduct is a mere loss in type precision, rather than a completely wrong type.


great, thanks! Interesting, I never thought about the possibility of annotating Zs explicitly as Bases. I don't think this will ever happen in my code but it's good to know about! Thanks for your advice!

@Darkdragon84 That was a trimmed-down example of what could go wrong. If you had a list[Base] that you accumulated with another operation, and after that operation the list happened to be filled with Zs, if you unpack the list into make_product, the result would also statically be inferred as MixedProduct - which is wrong.

I see, indeed. I will look out for such a case. Interesting that such a seemingly simple disambiguation can have such complex consequences...
